# salesforce commerce - checkout flow - payment - "purchase now" button won't execute apexAdapter

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce, flow-screen-component

My problem occurs during a screen flow (Checkout flow).
The "Submit Payment" button (which is part of a the payment component) doesn't execute anything while it should execute (for my understanding) the apex adapter that is linked to the gateway provider that is linked to the gateway object which its id is passed as value to the payment component.  I'm already after so many tests to find out how to let that button execute the adapter but with no success.

The Payment component is some sort of "provided" component which I have no access to. I say "provided" since it's not listed in the provided screen components list which you can find [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp.htm&type=5).

I've taken care of the following:

- The gateway object is "Active" and set with gateway provider and named credentials.
- The gateway provider is linked to the apex adapter.
- the apex adapter class is global and implements commercepayments.PaymentGatewayAdapter and includes the global method processRequest which returns commercepayments.GatewayResponse type of object. It also includes a System.debug line so I can locate it in the debug logs.
- The store's "Card Payment Gateway" integration configuration is linked with the gateway object.

thanks for helpers!

[image]
[image]